# Apply conditional formatting to whole rows only if multiple rows render true?

Tags: google-sheets

I have an advertising campaign tracker that have rows for name, jobcode, startdate and endate. Multiple lines have the same job code, but each of them can have a different end date. I need to apply conditional formatting to all rows that have an enddate that has passed – but only if the end date has passed for all rows with the same jobcode. I have searched this forum and various places online without luck, I really would appreciate your advice on this.

I have created a sample sheet that you may look at. I have created a formatted sample of what I want to achieve at the bottom. Feel free to play on the top one.

[Sample Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Fzj98VG2wvBZ3lC9jPxhDmTEIKx5e9PaEj_VWPtaaps/edit?usp=sharing)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: so is this `excel` or `google-spreadsheet`?

Comment: well, google sheets mainly, but figured a solution would probably work well in both apps. sorry for confusion

Comment: This formula works when applied to say column `A`: `=countifs($D$3:$D$8,D3,$G$3:$G$8,">="&today())=0`, but when it's applied to `A:G` it only works on column `A` and `B:G` all becomes highlighted. If you can work out that kink, you'll be good to go.

Comment: Thanks for your input mate, I am praying someone here might be able to add to your great start as I am clueless on this one....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This formula will work when applied to `A3:G8` (or further down the spreadsheet):

`=countifs($D$3:$D$8,$D3,$G$3:$G$8,">="&today())=0`

the $D in `$D3` is to keep the formatting formula locked on column D as it applied across columns `A:G`.

Use this in the Custom Formula option of the Conditional Formatting

Comment: I thought it would be easy to add in another criteria to check against with your formula, but I can't get it to work. Would you mind enlightening me on how I can add an additional check for a new "status" row that needs to be completed with certain text also? Whichever way i add that criterion in it stops working. I have updated the sample sheet with this column if you have a spare minute over :-)

Comment: CF is kind of tricky @HenrikSöderlund: This works: `=and($E$3:$E$8="DONE",Countifs($D$3:$D$8,$D3,$H$3:$H$8,">="&today())=0)`